# reloading page after fetching data from ajax

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I am using ajax to fetch data dynamically, but there is a problem. When I refresh the page the fetched data is lost.  I want the data to remain the same after I refresh the page.

Suppose this is my page:

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Index Page</title>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
/* fetching data which matches the keyword*/
function Search()
    {
    $.post("search.php", {search_word: $('#searchInput').val()} , function(data){ 
    if(data){
        $('#results').show();                   
        $("#results").append(data);                 
    }
    });
    }
</script>
</head>

<body>
<input type="text" value="" id="searchInput"/>
<input type="button" value="Search" onclick="Search();"/>
<div id="results" style="display:none"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

When I click on the search button the data which came in results div would be gone after refreshing the page.

Comment: You should provide the community with some of your code so we can see what you're trying to do and provide you with detailed help.

Comment: Suppose there is a div whose id is demoDiv and the response data from search page came in this div,now when I refresh the page this div data will gone away...But I want data would remain here after reloading the page...Is this understandable to you now what is my problem???

Comment: Yes, can you edit your question to include example code you're using? maybe the ajax load section?

Comment: You can try using jquery cookies or html5 web sql, or just save it into a database

Answer (score 1):

Save that data in `session` or in `database` and then fetch from there 
because after refreshing page `get` and `post` variables destroy automatically.

Comment: yes when you get content then again post that value on same page again and again

Answer (score 1):

Consider using cookie data.

This jQuery plugin will do the trick:
http://plugins.jquery.com/project/cookie

```
$.cookie('example', 'foo'); //the name is example and that value is foo.
```

getting the cookie's value is simple...

```
alert($.cookie('example');
```

So after you load your data dynamically you could either store that data in a cookie. Though this may be a bad solution if your fetching a large amount of data.

This question is hard to answer due to the lack of example code and therefore not understanding your intent or how/what you're doing.